# spring boot ask for login only once and remain logged even if i reload it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication

I'm learning spring security, i've already met this problem in another project, i've copied this simple rest api just to see if it was going to happen again. When i reach a protected endpoint, it check the validity of the request, but only once. In fact i can stop thr application, close the browser, and reopen anything, but still is logged in and does not ask password anymore. I've also tried postman to see if it was a browser problem, (chekced with chrome and firefox), but it's still the same, the first time it ask me a password, and then once logged, in postman using basic auth, i can even login using only the username withouth saying any password.

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

@GetMapping
public String home() {
    return "Hello, World!";
}

@GetMapping("/user")
public String user() {
    return "Hello, User!";
}

@GetMapping("/admin")
public String admin() {
    return "Hello, Admin!";
}

}
```

security config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import 
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
```

public class SecurityConfig {

```
@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
    UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("admin")
            .password("password")
            .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                auth.antMatchers("/").permitAll();
                auth.antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER");
                auth.antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN");
            })
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .build();
}
```

}

Comment: You are using basic auth, after successful authentication you will keep sending the username/password. You also use the defaults which means a session gets created and a session cookie as well. That session cookie will remain even after you close the browser, if the session hasn't timed out you are still logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot by default uses an embedded tomcat to run your application

In case you have already built your jar and you just shut down normally the app and restart it again, then it is normal that you still see the authentication existing.

From tomcat [doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html#Disable_Session_Persistence)

> Whenever Apache Tomcat is shut down normally and restarted, or when an
> application reload is triggered, the standard Manager implementation
> will attempt to serialize all currently active sessions to a disk file
> located via the pathname attribute. All such saved sessions will then
> be deserialized and activated (assuming they have not expired in the
> mean time) when the application reload is completed.

What the above means is that the security authentication which would exist in a HttpSession in ram memory would be transfered to hard disk during shutdown and reloaded again in ram memory during restart if it has not expired yet.

The above will answer why the application remembers you even after you restart.

As to you closing the browser I think you are closing the browser's tab and so the httpBasic header remains when you reopen a new tab and send a request to the restarted application.

To avoid this situation that tomcat stores session and reloads them during restart, for `tomcat8` as described in documentation you can add in your `src/main/resources` a `META-INF/context.xml` file. Inside `context.xml` you should add the line `<Manager pathname="" />`.

Comment: it didn't work, i've also searched on internet to see an alternative way to disable the session persistance so in the application.proprieties i've tried server.servlet.session.persistent=false but it's still asking for password only once  (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <Manager pathname="" />
) this is how i wrote the context.xml in META_INF

Comment: i use Ubuntu, i've tried to run the application on a windows computer but the problem persist

Comment: @leo___ try together with the above fix to also clean cookies from browser or use incognito window

Comment: incognito window worked